# Multiple whereHas calls are not being aggregated together

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've got multiple calls to `whereHas()` on an instance of `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` (`$cars`):

```
$cars->whereHas("finance", function (Eloquent\Builder $query) {
    $query->where('term'...)
}
$cars->whereHas("finance", function (Eloquent\Builder $query) {
    $query->where('payment'...)
}
```

Is there some way to aggregate the `where`(s) together without needing to do all the `where` calls within the containing `whereHas`?

The SQL query being executed:

```
SELECT id
FROM `cars`
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT `finance`.`payment` as payment
    FROM `finance`
     INNER JOIN `car_finance` ON `finance`.`id` = `car_finance`.`finance_id`
     WHERE `car_finance`.`car_id` = `cars`.`id`
       AND `payment` >= 50)
  AND EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM `finance`
     INNER JOIN `car_finance` ON `finance`.`id` = `car_finance`.`finance_id`
     WHERE `car_finance`.`car_id` = `cars`.`id`
       AND `payment` <= 200)
  AND EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM `finance`
     INNER JOIN `car_finance` ON `finance`.`id` = `car_finance`.`finance_id`
     WHERE `car_finance`.`car_id` = `cars`.`id`
       AND `term` = 48)
  AND EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM `finance`
     INNER JOIN `car_finance` ON `finance`.`id` = `car_finance`.`finance_id`
     WHERE `car_finance`.`car_id` = `cars`.`id`
       AND `deposit` = 1000)
  AND `active` = 1
```

The SQL query that I would like to be executed:

```
SELECT *
        FROM cars
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT *
        FROM `finance`
     INNER JOIN `car_finance` ON `finance`.`id` = `car_finance`.`finance_id`
     WHERE `car_finance`.`car_id` = `cars`.`id`
    AND deposit = 1000
    AND term = 48
    AND payment >= 50
    AND payment <= 200)
  AND active = 1
```

Comment: I ran into this issue a while back and wrote this package that does what you're looking for:  https://github.com/Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter  More specifically [Filtering Related Models](https://github.com/Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter#ways-to-filter-related-models)

Answer (score 0):

Your question it's not clear but I think you want this:

```
$cars->whereHas("finance", function ($query) {
   $query->where('deposit', 1000)->where('term', 48)
     ->whereBetween('payment', 50, 200);
})->where('active', 1)->get();
```

Comment: What part of the question is not clear? This  unfortunately does not take into account "without needing to move the where calls within the containing whereHas".

Comment: you want to use where outside the whereHas?